# release an iphone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, build

i try to generate a nameproject.app after the build/Release.the build has succeed but i didn't find the file nameproject.app under product !! (it seems to be availble but the option "show in Finder" is disabled ) . My question is how to generate nameproject.app?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to Build and Archive your project. You may need to check what code signing settings you have in the project and executable.

Use the Organiser to select your archive version and then you can Share that version of your project. You will need to select the correct code signing again. It will allow you to save the .ipa file where you want.

Drag and drop the .ipa file into iTunes and then sync with your iPhone.

Here are some more detailed instructions including screenshots;

[Here are some more detailed instructions](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/how-to-distribute-ad-hoc-build-with-xcode-4/)

Comment: i have resolve the issue. the  option "Per-Configuration Build Products Path" and update it's value to $(SYMROOT)

Answer (score 0):

Click on: Product - Archive (You must select IOS devices into active scheme and you not select IOS Simulator scheme).
When the run is terminated it's open the organizer view.
Right click on your app - Show in finder.
Right click on your archive into finder - Show package content - Products - Applications and here you find your file.app

Comment: i have resolve the issue. the option "Per-Configuration Build Products Path" and update it's value to $(SYMROOT)
thank you so much :D